# How do I supply data to the migrations seed method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I use migrations with the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initializer. It calls the migrations `Configuration` class every time the app is started. That config class has a `Seed(MyContext context)` method.

How do I pass data into the `Configuration` class, so I can use it in the `Seed()` method?

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext> {

  public Configuration() {
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
  }

  protected override void Seed(MyContext context) {
    // seed here
    base.Seed(context);
  }

}
```

Comment: Where is the data you want to pass in?

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/seed-database-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: @Colin that is an example of the older initializers. I specicially want to use the migrations initializer. Location of data is not terribly important. I need a hook into that seed method, or its class, or something in the pipeline which invoked it.

Comment: No, it's just using a different initialiser. You fetch your data from wherever it is and you add it right in the Seed method where your "// seed here" comment is. Here is another example: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/

Comment: @Colin not sure I understand your point, but I want to use the migrations initializer (`MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`), not the "older" ones. The problem is that it doesnt have any way to pass data to it, so that I can use that data in the class' seed method. Unless I hardcode the seed data, which is obviously not an option. The data needs to be passed in from the main app, which calls that initializer, not from the db. I dont want the seed method to know anything about my domain, its only role is to accept data and to seed, well, thats what I'd like, but it doesnt work that way, I think.

Comment: It takes a `DbContext` as a parameter! Doesn't it already know quite a lot about your domain?

Comment: The db is empty! It's a seed method after all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As of the current bits, this cannot be done. So I've gone back to using the old school initializers.

Comment: You create a model based on your domain. You tell your context what the model is by adding `DbSet`. EF then generates the database based on your model. The `Seed` method gets the `DbContext` as a parameter but you are resisting hard coding, or reading from file, directly in the Seed method because you "dont want the seed method to know anything about my domain". That is your choice, but I think it is a poor choice so I've downvoted

Comment: @Colin You downvoted because you work differently, rather than my way makes no sense? Nice!

Comment: Ok, to clarify, I also think it makes no sense :D

Comment: @Colin We need to pull the data from various sources, and so we have an elaborate config system. I want to be able to pass data into the seed method. That's the implication of "seed". We cannot read from the various dbs there (and those dbs are locked down except according to a certain contract, which is in our config system), and we don't harcode data in there as that's plain stupid. We need to **pass** seed/config data into the seed method, rather than read it there. Seriously, I don't understand your problem.

Comment: @hbob - I realize this post is > 2 years old now, but this is possible. The MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion has a constructor that accepts a Configuration object (derived from DbMigrationsConfiguration). I am not sure if this was added to the bits subsequent to your original question, but it is now possible. I also think it is a perfectly reasonable thing to do (so I added an upvote to your answer and question).

Answer (score 0):

Main idea behind migrations is to provide a way to keep the DB matching the state of the C# models. Migrations are not supposed to create data in your database. Hence there are no parameters you can pass into process of updating the database.

You'll need to come up with a better way to add data into your DB.

Comment: This is wrong. There is a [Seed method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829453%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) specifically for adding data to your db.

Comment: sigh... @hbob Yes, you can add data there. Does not mean that is the best place for this task. Problem with this method that there is no good way to pass parameters there. And do you want the same data seeded after every migration?

Comment: It's there for a reason, and I want to use it. At every migration yes. It's the one thing stopping me moving from old-school initializers to the migration initializer. Not being able to hook into that config class is an oversight in the API design.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the purpose? why so rigid requirements? Can you not insert data from within migrations scripts?

Comment: Because that makes the most sense, there is a seed method, but it doesnt allow you to supply data?! So you need to seed hardcoded values, or read from a db. Both make no sense and closely couples that set of classes to something not even in the project. So I've gone back to using the older initializers for now, eg. CreateIfNotExists, etc., which have seed method which are more usable.